# Multiple columns in one single row mysql

Tags: mysql

## My returned query looks like this

| Name | Type 1 | Type 2 | Type 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 |  |  |
| John |  | 3 |  |
| John |  |  | 5 |
| Ronn | 11 |  |  |
| Ronn |  | 9 |  |
| Ronn |  |  | 7 |

but I want them to be in a single row that looks like this, what functions should I use?

| Name | Type 1 | Type 2 | Type 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 | 3 | 5 |
| Ronn | 11 | 9 | 7 |

## Here's my query

```
SELECT c.name, 
       if(t.type = A, SUM(t.amount), "") AS Type 1,
       if(t.type = B, SUM(t.amount), "") AS Type 2,
       if(t.type = C, SUM(t.amount), "") AS Type 3
FROM 
       customer AS c,
       transaction AS t,
       t_detail AS td

WHERE
       c.id = td.id
       AND t.type IN ("A", "B", "C")

GROUP BY c.id, t.type
```

#### customer

id = fk to t_details

#### transaction

amount

type

#### t_detail

t_id
id = FK. customer id

Comment: Can you give sample data for your two tables?

Comment: @Kevin see edited ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to provide more information ( sample data) but seems like  you need to group by name:

```
SELECT c.name, 
       SUM(case when t.type = 'A' then t.amount end) AS Type1,
       SUM(case when t.type = 'B' then t.amount end) AS Type2,
       SUM(case when t.type = 'C' then t.amount end) AS Type3
FROM  customer AS c
inner join transaction as t
   on c.id = t.id
   AND t.type IN ("A", "B", "C")
GROUP BY c.name
```

also always use explicit join.

Comment: it still return the same table

Comment: it sums up all the values and returns to 4th column(type 3)

Comment: thanks man, problem solved! Thank you. Been trying to solve this for more than an hour now, thanks

Comment: You don't actually need "AND t.type IN ("A", "B", "C")"